# Eager loading related model using query scope

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Say I have a model `Box` which holds many widgets. The widgets can be active or inactive (boolean). The `Widget` model has a query scope which can filter results:

models/box.php:

```js
class Box extends Eloquent
{
    public function widgets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Widget');
    }
}
```

models/widget.php:

```js
class Widget extends Eloquent {

    public function box()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Box');
    }

    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->whereActive(true);
    }
}
```

Query scopes make it easy to get all widgets for a given box:

```js
$box_widgets = Box::find($box_id)->widgets()->active()->get(); 
// returns an Eloquent\Collection containing a filtered array of widgets
```

But how can I use `scopeActive` to eliminate this eager loading `with` method's conditional function?

```js
$boxes = Box::with(array('widgets', function ($q)
{
    $q->active();
}))->get();
```

It seems like there's probably a shorthand for accessing a relation's scope,  something like `Box::with('widgets->active')` or `Box::with('widgets.active')` but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Suppose most of the time you want only active widgets, so I suggest:

```
public function widgets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Widget')->whereActive(true);
}

public function widgetsDisabled()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Widget')->whereActive(false);
}
```

You can setup up more, for example for loading all at once, like you have now.

Then eager load as easily as that:

```
Box::with('widgets')... // loads only active
```

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Just to clarify, these are methods of the Box model. This also provides the sets with different names, which is great.

Comment: Yes, of course they belong to the Box model. Hving different names for the relations like you have is great indeed as you can make the code verbose and easy to use