# Laravel $appends

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to ignore all my **$appends** in my **User** model just for one time. I need all those every time on my app but this one time I don't need it and it's slowing down the performance of my query.

I need the correct way to do it. I've been search like 1 week for this solution and nothing.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable,
        SoftDeletes,
        FilterTrait,
        HasRoles;


    public $appends = [
       'fullName',
       'name',
       'since',
       'newCustomer',
       'image_URL',
       'th_roles'
   ];
...
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I think the `$appends` was made for always appending. I think you need to use the scope feature. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942021/eager-loading-related-model-using-query-scope but yes, you would need to rewrite everything. If you find some other option please post.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know and that's why I'm using $appends, but only for one occasion I don't need 'newCustomer'. For sure, if I find something I'll post it.

Answer (score 3):

Values listed in **$appends** variable are appended only when your model is converted into an array, e.g. when you return it from your controller. In order to avoid that you should clear **$appends** variable on all objects you return, e.g.:

```
public function someController() {
  $user = User::find(1);
  $user->setAppends([]);

  return $user; //no values will be appended
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I'm returning the array as json, but the getter it will already had executed, it's a query and it is slowing down the process.
I'm trying to avoid calling the 'newCustomer' append completely.

Did you understand what I'm trying to accomplish?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the getter gets executed it means you're accessing newCustomer property somewhere... Throw an exception from your getter and see where it's called